# What is the use of IPFS node in self hosted graph-node

Tags: subgraph

I was going through [graph-node](https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node) documentation which seems to work as backend for the graphql service & will also be responsible for saving any data to database. But I'm unable to understand what is the need of an IPFS node there, I mean when hosting on our own, can't we simply host it using normal web2 server, & please also provide any reference to how that IPFS intergration will work if available, Thanks.